# How to connect GOIP GSM Gateway with SIP Phone

Tags: voip, gsm, gateway

Is there any way to connect a sip/ip phone directly with a goip GSM gateway.

I am using GOIP16
Firmware Version:       GST-1.01-68

Comment: Hi, have you had any success? I am dealing with a similar issue.

Comment: I talked with the officials but they said that it is not possible to connect  GOIP16 to sip phone directly.